# Data cleaning in R, aggregation of multiple columns

Tags: r, data-science

I am trying to find out the max no of attacks done by gname in each region_text in each year.

```
iyear  region_text  gname  nkill 
1970   asia         xyz    1      
1970   asia         xyz    1
1970   asia         abc    1
1970   africa       bbb    1
1970   africa       bbb    1
1971   asia         nnn    2
1971   asia         mmm    2
1971   asia         nnn    2
1971   africa       kkk    0
```

Solution needed

```
iyear  region_text  gname  nkill  nattacks(new column)
1970   asia         xyz    2      2
1970   africa       bbb    2      2
1971   asia         nnn    2      2
1971   africa       kkk    0      1
```

I have data for 45 years(1970-2015) divided into 12 regions(asia, africa...)

I have tried aggregate function but it could not tell me the no of attacks grouped by each year instead for all 45 years.
I am a newbie to R, need to know which direction I need to go. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the code you tried with aggregate? It's likely you're already pretty close to a solution. Also, why is only one `gname` value represented for each year/region combination in your "Solution needed"?

Comment: Are you grouping by the first 3 columns?